# Binding to a variable, Binding to a function and two way binding in TS angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, data-binding

I'm trying to bind a variable, a method and two way binding. But get errors on all 3. Below is the code:

- **bind method:**

> .html

```
<ion-label class="banner_small" [ngModel]="getUserName()"></ion-label>
```

> .ts

```
getUserName() {
    return "test";
  }
```

Error is:

```
ERROR ReferenceError: $event is not defined
```

- **bind variable**

> .html

```
<ion-label class="banner_small" [ngModel]="userName"></ion-label>
```

> .ts

```
export class MyApp {
  public userName: string;
constructor(...){
this.userName = "test";
...
}
```

error is:

```
 Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
```

- **two way binding**

> .html

```
<ion-label class="banner_small" [(ngModel)]="getUserName()"></ion-label>
```

> .ts

```
getUserName() {
    return "test";
  }
```

error is:

```
 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 14 in [getUserName()=$event]
```

Answer (score 0):

First mistake, you are trying to use ngModel on a label. ngModel should be used over inputs.

If you just want to bind to a label, use **`[innerHtml]`**

```
<ion-label class="banner_small" [innerHtml]="getUserName()"></ion-label>
```